# How to completely center a Unicode math symbol within its parent element?

Tags: css, unicode, centering, css-animations

I am trying to implement a CSS-based animation involving a single Unicode character:

**HTML**

```
<div class="spinner">⊗</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.spinner {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 42pt;
    margin: 50px;
    animation: spin 0.5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

<sup>* I've omitted the vendor-specific prefixes in this example.</sup>

However, when I view the page in my browser (Firefox 20.0), the character is slightly off-center, resulting in a "wobbly" animation.

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/bBaVN/77/

How can I completely center the character?

Answer (score 4):

**Proof of Concept using SVG**

Consider the following:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <span class="spinner">
      <svg {...many other attributes...} class="logo">
         ...path code...
      </svg>
  </span>
</wrap>
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/3G3U7/

I found a SVG version of the symbol at:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2297/index.htm

I had to take the SVG, open it in Adobe Illustrator and then reset the view port (bounding box?) using `object->artboards->fit to artwork bounds`.

I then saved as SVG and then cut-paste the `<svg>` block into the demo, and finally, I added the `class="logo"` attribute to the `<svg>` tag.

For styling, I used the following CSS:

```
.spinner {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
    left: 75px;
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}
.logo {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I set the display type to `block` for both `.logo` and `.spinner`, and both have the same height and width (use a square box for best results.

Seems to work.   The hardest part was learning how to set up the SVG inline image.  I found the following reference useful: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `line-height` to `45px` on `.spinner`, this will ensure that the containing `span` element is as high as it is wide. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bBaVN/86/). Now there is a little less movement, but it still doesn't look like it is not moving around at all.

Another way to get it to rotate around the center of character instead of around the center of the containing `span` would be to play around with `-vendorspecificprefix-transform-origin`. You could set it to rotate around another point e.g. setting it to: `23px 34px` would set the `x` and `y` coordinates for the point to rotate around.

I think the fact that it still looks like it moves around a little bit might be due to the character not being rendered as a perfect circle, you could try rendering it in a different font, changing point sizes of the font, or even turning `text-rendering: optimizelegibility;` on or off might make a difference there.

The default value for `-vendorspecificprefix-transform-origin` is `50% 50%`, this suggests that if you make sure that the character inside the element is perfectly centered, and you set the animation on the containing element, it should rotate exactly around the the center, and then playing with `-vendorspecificprefix-transform-origin` would only make things worse.

Another thought I'm having, by setting the point size of the text to `42pt`, the width of the containing span becomes `45px`, now `50%` of that would be `22.5px`, maybe it would work if you made the point size of the text a bit bigger, or just set the width and the height of the containing span to `46px`, then `50%` would be `23px`, which might make the difference with the current movement.

**Update:**

I was able to get it to be centered perfectly in [Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/bBaVN/90/) ([and in FireFox](http://jsfiddle.net/bBaVN/93/)) by using a mono-space font `Courier`, manually setting the `line-height`, `height` and `width` of the `span`  to center the character, and then forcing the character to look more like a circle by moving it over by `0.5px` using `-webkit-transform: translate()`.

```
.spinner {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 42pt;
    line-height: 50px;  
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    margin: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    font-family: courier;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0.5px, 0px)}
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(0.5px, 0px)}
}
```

I think the fact that I need 2 jsFiddle's to demonstrate for different browsers kind of answers the question about if you should be doing it this way, I think the differences in font-rendering between browsers will ensure that you can't do this reliably without browser detection.

Comment: viewing your "perfectly centered in Chrome" link today on Chrome 61.0.3163.100, it bobs up and down by about 3-5 pixels, so I assume that this technique is pretty fragile.

Comment: @uglycoyote, indeed it is, indeed it does, I hope the answer doesn't come off as trying to sell itself as a reliable approach, I was just fiddling around seeing what could be done at the time. providing commentary in the hope it might provide some insights/possible approaches to the problem for future readers, or even just to show what has or has not already been tried, by all means go for the SVG answer if SVG is an option :)